# LINQ StartWith vs. Substring

Tags: c#, linq

What is the *difference* between the two, and why one *works* while the other *doesn't*? The code filters file name that starts with `"L_01"`. I only get results with `.StartWith("L_01")` but not with `.Substring(0,4) == "L_01"`, and I do not see any difference between the two.

```
// Return results
Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(p => 
    System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p).StartsWith("L_01"));

// Return no result
Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(p => 
    System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p).Substring(0,4) == "L_01"))
```

Comment: **First** is **better** since second *throws exception* on `L.xml` file

Comment: "I only get results with `.StartsWith("L_01")`" - is that because the second approach is throwing an exception (as Dmitry notes), and you're swallowing that exception?

Comment: [FYI](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L2525-L2572)

Comment: Really, use debugger. Then at least you could have shown us exact string which produces unexpected results for you. As of now - all answers will be just guesswork.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("StartsWith " + (@"L_01234324".StartsWith("L_01")));` and 
            `Console.WriteLine("SubString " + (@"L_01234324".Substring(0,4) == "L_01"));` both return true in my project. I cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: What @Evk says. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve], and explain what "doesn't work" means. There's no need to use an unreproducible `Directory.GetFiles(path)` here, as we can't look on your filesystem. Create a hardcoded `List<string> { "...", "..." }` to execute the `Where()` on. If that doesn't reproduce your issue (which I can tell you it doesn't), then the problem isn't in `StartsWith` nor `Substring`, but in your data.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I did just that like how Chriz did in his sample, and both return true. That's why I post the question with original code including GetFiles since I can't "guess" a possible cause, and I would not have known I ran into "exception on short" as explained in Dmitry Bychenko's answer when running into string shorter than the substring.

Comment: Debug. Run `Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList()` and inspect its values. Then create a [mcve] with those values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first

```
 .StartsWith("L_01")
```

is **better**, since second

```
 .Substring(0,4) == "L_01")
```

*throws exception* on *short* (less than `4` characters long) file names like `L.xml`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`  startIndex plus length indicates a
>   position not within this instance.

When *exception* thrown (and *swallowed*, since you *don't see* it), e.g.

```
try {
  ...

  var files = Directory
    .GetFiles(path)
    .Where(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p).Substring(0,4) == _01"));

  foreach (var file in files) {
    ...
  } 
}
catch {
  // on exception thrown the loop will be broken and this code will be executed
}
```

you can well *lose* some files; Imagine that `Directory.GetFiles(path)` returns files in this order:

```
 L_01.xml  <- you've got it
 L_1.xml   <- exception here
 L_011.xml <- this will be lost
```

And you've got only `L_01.xml` proceeded

Comment: This is a reason why the first one might be better, but it doesnt answer the question why `.Substring(0,4) == "L_01"` doenst give results

Comment: @Chriz actually it might; my guess is that the reason OP isn't getting results with `Substring` is that they have a `try`/`catch` block that is swallowing the exception that is happening

Comment: Possible, but then the OP didnt post his full code snippet. I argued with the given information+ If it works in the first place in the same directory there _should_ be some results in the second place as well

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, many thanks. that solves my problem. I realized there were string shorter than 4 characters, and did not know SubString throws exception when comparing to string shorter than its length.